# Does such a Galois extension exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, an imaginary quadratic field. Does there exist a finite Galois extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$ which contains $K$ such that $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $S_3$? Here $S_3$ is the symmetric group in 3 letters.

I just don't know how to deal with such an "existence" question. If there exists such a $L$, can we have a concrete example? Many thanks.

Comment: The first example of an extension $L$ with Galois group $S_3$ over the rationals, covered in most texts on Galois theory, happens to contain $K$ as a subfield. So here's my suggestion. Can you name an extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ with Galois group $S_3$?

Comment: @jyki I feel it pretty hard to think of even a single example. But what I want to see here is a general method for determine the existence of such a Galois extension. :)

Comment: Have you seen any splitting fields of a cubic polynomial? BTW you need to get at least the three first letters of a username right for the ping to work. Only the flag summoned me here.

Comment: HINT: consider $L$ the splitting field of $x^3-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Consider the splitting field of $x^6+3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Define $\alpha = 3^{1/6}e^{i\pi/6}$. Easy to see $\alpha\in L$ and $e^{i\pi/3}\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Thus $L = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. The irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^6+3$, and hence $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = 6$. $\sqrt{-3}\in L$ and hence $K$ is contained in $L$. $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is either $S_3$ or $C_6$. Suppose $C_6$. Then all subgroups of $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is normal and hence all intermediate fields between $L$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are Galois  extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$. However, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})\subset L$ is not a Galois extension over $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}) \cong S_3$.

Comment: This is fine, but would not have been my first choice :-)